# Rake task to populate database at Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq, rake-task

I need to populate once the `Heroku` database with initial data scraped from an external website with `Nokogiri`. After the initial population task, the database will be updated by periodic jobs with `sidekiq` + `sidekiq-cron`.

Is it possible to use a rake task within the remote application environment to feed the database? 
 My rake task would fetch names and other attributes from an external website and write them to the database, like in the example below:

```
lib/tasks/feed.rake

desc "Fetch data and feed the database"
task :feed_database => :environment do
  require 'nokogiri'
  require 'open-uri'

  range = (1..100)
  url  = "http://www.example.com"
  doc  = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

  range.each do |num|
    name   = doc.at_css("tr:nth-child(#{num})).text
    Model.create(name: name)
  end
end
```

From my remote console I would use either the following command:

```
$ heroku run rake feed_database
```

or the following commands:

```
$ heroku run console
$ rake feed_database
```

However there is [little documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rake) at `Heroku` about rake tasks, and it seems that there are not well explained limitations on using rake commands.

Comment: You can totally do that. Are you experiencing any specific issue?

Comment: I am still designing my application, I need time before deploying. I wanted to be sure when time comes that I am not doing wrong.